# Setting Jenkins build name from package.json version value

Tags: json, jenkins

I want to include the value of the "version" parameter in package.json as part of the Jenkins build name.

I'm using the Jenkins Build Name Setter plugin - https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin

So far I've tried to use PROPFILE syntax in the "Build name macro template" step:

```
${PROPFILE,file="./mainline/projectDirectory/package.json",property="\"version\""}
```

This successfully creates a build, but includes the quotes and comma surrounding the value of the version property in package.json, for example:

```
"0.0.1",
```

I want just the value inside returned, so it reads

```
0.0.1
```

How can I do this? Is there a different plugin that would work better for parsing package.json and getting it into the template, or should I resort to some sort of regex for removing the characters I don't want?

UPDATE:

I tried using token transforms based on reading the Token Macro Plugin documentation, but it's not working:

```
${PROPFILE%\"\,#\",file="./mainline/projectDirectory/package.json",property="\"version\""}
```

still just returns

However, using only one escaped character and only one of # or % works. No other combinations I tried work.

```
${PROPFILE%\,,file="./mainline/projectDirectory/package.json",property="\"version\""}
```

which returns `"0.0.1"` (comma removed)

```
${PROPFILE#\"%\"\,,file="./mainline/projectDirectory/package.json",property="\"version\""}
```

which returns `"0.0.1",` (no characters removed)

---

**UPDATE:**
Tried to use the new Jenkins Token Macro plugin's JSON macro with no luck.

Jenkins Build Name Setter set to update the build name with Macro:

```
${JSON,file="./mainline/pathToFiles/package.json",path="version"}-${P4_CHANGELIST}
```

Jenkins build logs for this job show:

```
10:57:55 Evaluated macro: 'Error processing tokens: Error while parsing action 'Text/ZeroOrMore/FirstOf/Token/DelimitedToken/DelimitedToken_Action3' at input position (line 1, pos 74):
10:57:55 ${JSON,file="./mainline/pathToFiles/package.json",path="version"}-334319
10:57:55                                                                          ^
10:57:55 
10:57:55 java.io.IOException: Unable to serialize org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.impl.JsonFileMacro$ReadJSON@2707de37'
```

Comment: Where is that PROPFILE-makro defined?

Comment: Yoiu probably have a copy-paste-error in your last code sample.

Comment: PROPFILE is not meant to be used with JSON, PROPFILE is for use with properties files (similar to ini files). It would probably be better to add support for JSON in a new macro. In addition the % and # are for removing things from the beginning and end of the string, not all occurrences in the string.

Comment: Ok, I could write a new macro, but I was hoping this one would work well enough for my purposes. I'm looking for removing instances from the beginning and end - specifically removing one `"` character at the beginning and two characters, one `"` and one `,` at the end of the string. That is not removing all occurrences in the string.

When I try PROPFILE#\"%\"\, I would expect it to remove these three characters, but it does not.

Comment: You can't mix transforms, only a single transform can be used. I implemented a JSON macro and released token-macro. It should be available if you install 2.1

Comment: Wow, thanks @slide! Ok, that was unclear to me, I understand now. Still not sure why more than one character (escaped) with a single transform didn't work.

Can you submit your JSON macro as the answer, along with the info that you provided about tokens (only being able to use one at a time)? Would love to give you points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I implemented a new macro JSON, which takes a file and a path (which is the key hierarchy in the JSON for the value you want) in token-macro-2.1. You can only use a single transform per macro usage.

Comment: Really nice, but can you add a short docu of all makros included to the plugin description?

Comment: Other plugins can create their own macros that can be used, so I can't really provide a list of them. The wiki page shows what plugins consume and produce macros (if the plugin developer added a tag to their page in the wiki).

Comment: But the Plugin itself comes with a lot of macros, which aren't documented. Would be nice to have a small list and description of those.

Comment: @slide I tried out the new updates for the Token Macro plugin in v2.1 with no luck - see my updates in the question above please. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you try ${JSON, file="./mainline/pathToFiles/package.json", path="version"}-${P4_CHANGELIST}

Comment: Hmm, ${JSON,file="package.json",path="version"} just gives me "Error: package.json not found" which suggests that root is not the root of my workspace? I'd log an issue but no tracker. :)

Comment: There is a tracker https://issues.jenkins.io. Select token-macro as the component.

Comment: @slide when I use the token macro I get this message: Failed to evaluate name macro:org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.MacroEvaluationException: Error processing tokens. Do you know what is the reason?

Comment: @AlvaroMaravi I would need more information than that, like what does your token string look like, etc.

Comment: @slide my Build name is the following: SQ_${JSON, file="./package.json", path="version"}. When I built my freestyle job I got this message:

Failed to evaluate name macro:org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.MacroEvaluationException: Error processing tokens

Comment: @AlvaroMaravi can you try removing the space between , and path?

Comment: @slide I have tried with this SQ_${JSON,file="./package.json",path="version"} and I had the same error. I have Build Name and Description Setter version 2.2.0 and Token Macro Plugin version 293.v283932a_0a_b_49

Comment: @AlvaroMaravi can you share your json file? You said this is in the build name plugin?

Comment: @slide it's a freestyle project, yes I'm using those plugins.

Comment: @AlvaroMaravi Can you share the job config xml (redacted) and JSON file (redacted)?

Comment: @AlvaroMaravi I tried locally with the Build Name and Description Setter Plugin and a JSON file in the workspace with a version item in the object and it was fine. What version of Jenkins and the Token Macro Plugin are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Try the token transformations `#` and `%` (see [Token-Makro-Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Token+Macro+Plugin)):

> ${PROPFILE#"%",file="./mainline/projectDirectory/package.json",property="\"version\""}

Comment: Not quite, but this pointed me in the right direction (the documentation for Token Macro), thank you!

Comment: Updated my question with new info above, please let me know if you have any thoughts :)

Comment: Apparently this doesn't work, because only one transform can be used - see @slide's comments above.

Answer (score 1):

(This will only help if you are using pipelines. But for what it's worth,..)

What works for me is a combination of readJSON from the Pipeline Utility Steps plugin and directly setting currentBuild.displayName, thusly:

```
script {
    // readJSON from "Pipeline Utility Steps"
    def packageJson = readJSON file: 'package.json'
    def version = packageJson.version

    echo "Setting build version: ${packageJson.version}"
    currentBuild.displayName = env.BUILD_NUMBER + " - " + packageJson.version
    // currentBuild.description = "other cool stuff"
}
```

Omitting error handling etc obvs.